# Prevent specific USB device from automounting

Tags: arch-linux, udev, automounting

I have a SD card which is always inserted in my SD-card slot. However, I do not often use it (but do not want to take it out). Currently, it's being auto-mounted every time I start my computer. I feel this might over time wear out the SD card unnecessarily. So my question is: how to prevent this particular SD card from being mounted automatically? Whenever I need it, I'll mount it manually.

I've found this article:
http://www.tuxradar.com/answers/706

Which explains exactly what to do using HAL, but given that HAL is deprecated I'm looking for a way of doing this using udev.

Using Arch Linux.

Comment: Is it listed in your `/etc/fstab` and are you sure it is actually being mounted?  Normally unlisted disks are shown in the GUI but not actually mounted until you try to open them.

Comment: It's in fact not listed in `/etc/fstab`, but it becomes available automatically at `/var/run/media`, without any additional GUI interaction necessary...

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devices mentioned in /etc/fstab will be treated as mentioned there-in.
This will prevent whatever auto-system is used to deal with "unknown" devices, when attached.

https://superuser.com/a/439079/139040 includes the recommendation I came up with for how to deal-with/defeat the auto-mounting systems of OSX, but the concepts should translate.